# How can I extract published filepaths from the Tridion content management explorer?

Tags: tridion2009

I'm trying to determine the published URL of a page by performing a "where used" on a particular page template?

The fields that are available are: Page name, Publication, Comments and full path within Tridion.

Can someone let me know if this is possible or whether there are any alternatives?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use http://tridion.stackexchange.com for your Tridion questions.

Comment: Thanks Nuno.  Duly noted for next time.

Answer (score 2):

The publish paths are not visible in the CME by default.

Alternatives include:

- Experience Manager reflects your Staging or Preview site (and URLs).
- A template could construct the URL for you. Templates can detect where they're running and could add even a link only in preview to the (expected) published page.
- A GUI extension could add this to the interface.

Look at or consider [Bart Koopman's Preview extension](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/view_in_staging_live.aspx) for the third option.

Comment: Thanks Alvin and Bart.  We're using Tridion 2009 so we may have limited options at our disposal.  But I will look into the options above.